# How to find jupyter <nbextension require path> for Table of Contents (2) extension?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to install and enable [Table of Contents (2)](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/toc2/README.html) plugin using command-line.

The [docs](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) suggest that I can do the following

`jupyter nbextension enable <nbextension require path>`

How do I find this path for this extension?

Comment: why you don't just use the UI on http://localhost:8888/tree#nbextensions_configurator ?

Comment: because I'm using scripts to periodically bring up jupyter servers on several machines, and then bring them down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @jfbercher's comemnt in [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#947](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/947):

```
jupyter nbextension install <url>/toc2.zip --user
jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main
```

If a non-default directory is used in `nbextensions_configurator`, it can be obtained like [the code here](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/blob/bd6561d02ff7b51549d133ec4f8e7bf2c5b6db57/src/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/__init__.py#L181):

```
nbextension_dirs = nbapp_webapp.settings['nbextensions_path']
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution:

1/ Visit this unofficial list of nbextensions:

https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions.html

and pick the extension you want to enable. Say e.g. that I want to enable "Collapsible Headings", then

2/ type:

```
jupyter nbextension enable collapsible_headings/main
```

If the extension is enabled you will see an OK message.

So in general type:

```
jupyter nbextension enable <name_of_extension>/main
```

Most of the times it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this does seem like a bit of an oversight. I tried to install the configurator... but had issues.

The approach that worked for me was to look in `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions` or similar (you might need to use a `docker run image /bin/bash` if you are drinking too much koolaid - or your employer is forcing you to. ).

There is then a `.js` file in various directories which I think correspond to the extension names. E.g. `hinterland/hinterland.js` means the extension is called `hinterland/hinterland`.